# Unbounded Feasible Region

Tags: examples-counterexamples, linear-programming

I know that "Unbounded feasible regions may or may
not have an optimal solution." I know the example where unbounded feasible region has an optimal solution but I need two examples where a maximum and in another a minimum don't exist.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly.  You want (1) a feasible LPP where a maximum don't exist (2) a feasible LPP where a minimum don't exist?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

1. a feasible LPP where a maximum doesn't exist
   \begin{alignat}{3}
     \max\quad   & z = & 3x & + & 2y \\
     \text{s.t.} &     &  x & - &  y & \le -3 \\
                 &     & 5x & - & 7y & \le 10 \\
                 &     & \rlap{x,y \ge 0}
     \end{alignat}
   \begin{cases}
   y &\ge x - 3 \\
   y &\ge \dfrac{5x - 10}{7} \\
   x,y &\ge 0 \\
   z &= 3x + 2y \ge C_1 x + M
   \end{cases}
   for some constants $C_1> 0$ and $M \in \Bbb{R}$ independent of $x$ and $y$.
2. a feasible LPP where a minimum doesn't exists
   \begin{alignat}{3}
     \min\quad   & z = &   & 4x & - & 3y \\
     \text{s.t.} &     &   & 3x & - & 2y & \ge -8 \\
                 &     & - & 2x & + & 7y & \ge 10 \\
                 &     & \rlap{x,y \ge 0}
     \end{alignat}
   \begin{cases}
   y &\le \dfrac{3x + 8}{2} \\
   y &\ge \dfrac{2x + 10}{7} \\
   x,y &\ge 0 \\
   z &= 4x - 3y
   \end{cases}

As $x$ get larger, it is possible to choose some $y$ so that
\begin{cases}
\dfrac32 x &\le y \le \dfrac{3x + 8}{2} \\
y &\ge \dfrac{2x + 10}{7} \\
x,y &\ge 0 \\
z &= 4x - 3y \le 4x - 3\left( \dfrac32 x \right) = -\dfrac12 x
\end{cases}
Hence this LPP is unbounded and it has no minimum.

Comment: Can we say that if any simplex table contains a variable with non positive column then we are sure that the problem will be unbounded in that direction certainly. Next thatdirection can inturn point to unboundedness in some other direction

Comment: here's an example: http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/ebooks/or/Ch3/splcase1.htm

Comment: the z-row must be negative, and non positive column must contain at least one zero so as to maintain feasibility